# Handling `Run-time error 1004: No cells were found` when copying filtered table cells

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I have a procedure to copy specified cells of a table which are identified in 3 loops.  Sometimes there wouldn't be any data and that's not a problem,
but I'm getting `Run-time error '1004': No cells were found.` which prevents the code from going to the next loop.
I had tried `On Error Resume Next` but I will not get my response from the code with that.  Maybe there are more errors further and I won't see them because of `Resume Next`.

Here is my code:

```
If Sheets("hour report").Range("U1") = 1 Then
    For i = 1 To k3
        For n = 1 To k1
            Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, _
                Criteria1:=Sheets("hour report").Range("B" & i + 1)
            Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, _
                Criteria1:=Sheets("hour report").Cells(1, n + 2)

            On Error Resume Next
            Range("Table1[f1]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            Sheets("hour report").Activate
            Cells(i + 1, n + 2).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        Next n
    Next i
End If
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data. This would allow to reproduce your issue.

Comment: You need to show more code for this.  YOu have variables that we can't see accounted, e.g., k1 and k3.

Comment: Improved formatting with line breaks and formatting of code.  Altered text slightly.  Use of language could still be improved a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there with the `On Error Resume Next`.  That will stop the error occurring but, as you say, it will fall down further on.

If you remove error checking from the `SpecialCells` line, reinstate it and then check if the `SpecialCells` returned anything:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rFiltered As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rFiltered = Range("Table1[F1]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rFiltered Is Nothing Then
        rFiltered.Copy
        'Rest of code for when a range is returned.
    End If

End Sub
```